# Qt QWheelEvent failing in multi scroll

Tags: qt, scrollwheel

I am using **QWheelEvent** for zoom in and zoom out in a plot. When I scroll one by one, the program works good, but when multi scroll is used(rotate mouse wheel fast) the program does not work fine. I debug it and grasp that when I multi scroll to zoom in, some of events are false(zooming out).
can any one help me!
part of code:

```
bool zoom_out_scope=false;
bool zoom_in_scope=false;
if(event->angleDelta().y()==120)
   zoom_in_scope=true;
else
    zoom_out_scope=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed this on my laptop, `angleDelta` values are not always `+/-120`. Here are is a log from my laptop.

```
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-11,0))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-5,0))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-5,0))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(0,3))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-7,1))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase)
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-2,1))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase)
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-4,3))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase)
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-1,0))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-1,1))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase)
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(0,1))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(-1,1))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase)
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(0,3))
QWheelEvent(Qt::NoScrollPhase, pixelDelta=QPoint(0,0), angleDelta=QPoint(0,1))
```